# Showing a randomly scaled Brownian motion is a (local) Martingale.

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, local-martingales

Assume we work on a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F},(\mathscr{F})_{t\geq0}, \mathbb{P} )$

Let $B_t$ be a standard $\mathscr{F}_t$-Brownian motion and let $X$ be a positive random variable measurable with respect to $\mathscr{F}_0$. How do I show that $M_t = B_{Xt}$ is a local $\mathscr{F}_{Xt}$-Martingale and a $\mathscr{F}_{Xt}$-Martingale iff $\mathbb{E}\sqrt X < \infty$?

Writing $$M_t=\sqrt X \frac{1}{\sqrt X} B_{\frac{t}{(\sqrt X)^{-2}}} = \sqrt X \hat B^x_t$$ seems to be a step in a right direction. But I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Just write down the Martingale definition: since you condition on $\mathcal{F_t}$ , you may take your $\sqrt{X}$ out of the expectation and then apply the Martingale property of $B$

Comment: @Bananach, this would imply that it is always a Martingale? Which is apparently isn't according to the iff statement